# In Angular 5 , How should group number of click events and emit once only when user stop clicking

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a angular application (Angular5 + ngrx5).

In my app, users can click/select are number of options/items (just simple divs). such as  option1, option2, option3 ....  Multiple options can be selected.

Currently, users select one option, we trigger a service call to save a selected option. We do currency version number checks, so users have to wait the service call response (with latest version number) back before select the next option. It is not providing good UX.

Therefore, I prefer that users can keep clicking a number of options, once users stop clicking we make a single service call with multiple selections .

My question is that how to group number of click events and emit once only when user stop clicking? any examples or any suggestions?

I know rxjs debounce can drop emitted values.clicks, but I do not want to drop them I want to aggregate them in order to make a single service call.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this with a `setTimeout`.

On each click, you can build an array with your values.

Then, set a timer to send to the API. If it receives another request while waiting for that timer, cancel it, and start a new one.

```
handleClick(value) {
    this.values.push(value);

    // If there's a timer going, cancel it
    if (this.timer != null) {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }

    // Start a new one
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        // Send to your API
        // Make sure to clear your this.values array after the API call has returned
    }, 5000);
}
```

In the example above, it will only send the request after 5 seconds without a click event

Answer (score 3):

The rxjs way of achieving this.

```
const ajax=Rx.Observable.timer(4000).mapTo('ajaxcall')
Rx.Observable
 .fromEvent(click, 'click')
 .scan((acc,curr)=> ([curr,...acc]) ,[])
 .debounceTime(500)
 .mergeMap(arrClick=>{
console.log(arrClick) 
return ajax 
 }).subscribe()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7kbg4q2e/453/